# Tuple of lists to a dictionary? Character names as keys and the amount of paragraphs they have as values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
dialogue = (['Benvolio','Part, fools!\nPut up your swords; you know not what you do.'], 
            ['Tybalt', 'What, art thou drawn among these heartless hinds?\nTurn thee, Benvolio, look upon thy death.'],
            ['Benvolio', 'I do but keep the peace: put up thy sword,\nOr manage it to part these men with me.'],
            ['Tybalt', 'What, drawn, and talk of peace! I hate the word,\nAs I hate hell, all Montagues, and thee:\nHave at thee, coward!\n[They fight]\n[Enter, several of both houses, who join the fray;]\nthen enter Citizens, with clubs]'])
```

`dialogue` contains the whole play of Shakespeare (I've only included the first 4 lines)

output should be:

```
{"Character name":number of occurrences of each character}
```

so for my example^ it should say

```
{"Benvolio": 2, "Tybalt": 2}  # as each character appears 2 times
```

I am trying to count the number of times a character speaks. I am not interested in what's inside their specific dialogue. In my example, Benvolio speaks twice and Tybalt speaks twice hence both of their values in the dictionary being 2.
I don't understand how to use counter() to iterate over my tuple. I understand how to count if there is one list but how do I count the character names in all of the lists in the tuple?
Thanks

Comment: Why 45? Is that the number of paragraphs?

Comment: Is this the number of occurrences of each name in the list? Maybe: `collections.Counter(name for name, _ in dialogue)` ?

Comment: I just chose 45 at random. Yes the values are supposed to be the number of occurrences of each character

Comment: Your example is confusing, can you add a realistic output?

Comment: yes sorry ive edited.

Comment: Please be specific about what you are having trouble with. _"Any help"_ is too broad for Stack Overflow. [Ask]. If you tried and are encountering errors, provide a [mre] and the _full_ traceback of your error. Please take the [tour] and read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Your edit is a step in the right direction, but please _ask a specific question_. You have only provided a goal. What _specifically_ are you stuck with? Iterating over the tuple? Getting the character name/dialog from each element? Counting the number of lines in each element? Keeping track of this number for multiple characters?

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` will count the occurrences of a hashable item in a sequence. In your case, you want the first value in each list. This can be done with generator that selects that value.

```
from collections import Counter

dialogue = (['Benvolio','Part, fools!\nPut up your swords; you know not what you do.'],
            ['Tybalt', 'What, art thou drawn among these heartless hinds?\nTurn thee, Benvolio, look upon thy death.'],
            ['Benvolio', 'I do but keep the peace: put up thy sword,\nOr manage it to part these men with me.'],
            ['Tybalt', 'What, drawn, and talk of peace! I hate the word,\nAs I hate hell, all Montagues, and thee:\nHave at thee, coward!\n[They fight]\n[Enter, several of both houses, who join the fray;]\nthen enter Citizens, with clubs]'])

occurances = Counter(occurance[0] for occurance in dialogue)
print(occurances)
```

Comment: ok I get it now, thank you so much.